# WWW::Curl::Easy output not capture

Tags: perl, curl

```
use JSON;
use WWW::Curl::Easy;

my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_NOBODY,1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,3);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_VERBOSE,0);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL,$url);


my $response = (what to use here);

my %hash = decode_json($response);
$country = $hash->{body}->{country};
return $country;


#the output from url is in json format.
#but unable to capture that output in a response variable as object.
```

I am trying to capture reponse from `$url` which is in json format in variable then use JSON's `decode_json` method to convert that into hash structure to get country code. But I am not able to get the response in variable.

```
JSON Output:
{
    "headers": {
        "ipAddress": ["198.162.1.1"],
        "type": ["PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS"]
    },
    "body": {
        "country": {
            "isoCode": "CA",
            "name": "Canada",
            "geoNameId": 6251999
        },
        "continent": {
            "name": "North America",
            "code": "NA",
            "geoNameId": 6255149
        },
        "city": {
            "name": "Cranbrook",
            "geoNameId": 5931800
        },
        "traits": {
            "ipAddress": "198.162.1.1"
        },
        "location": {
            "latitude": 49.4999,
            "longitude": -115.7688,
            "timeZone": "America/Edmonton"
        },
        "postal": {
            "code": "V1C"
        },
        "subdivisions": [{
            "name": "British Columbia",
            "geoNameId": 5909050,
            "isoCode": "BC"
        }]
    },
    "statusCode": "OK"
}
200
```

Comment: The documentation of [WWW::Curl::Easy](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Curl) says it's not easy. It's _It is not intended to be a standalone module and because of this, the main libcurl documentation should be consulted for API details at http://curl.haxx.se_. Have you read that? I believe you are going to make your life easier by using [LWP::Simple](http://p3rl.org/LWP::Simple) instead.

Comment: @simbabque : Yes, i already done the same using LWP but as per requirements i need to implement this using WWW::Curl::Easy module. Here's the output json :              {"headers":{"ipAddress":["192.2.2.2"],"type":["PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS"]},"body":{"country":{"isoCode":"US","name":"United States","geoNameId":6252001},"continent":{"name":"North America","code":"NA","geoNameId":6255149},"city":{},"traits":{"ipAddress":"192.2.2.2"},"location":{"latitude":37.751,"longitude":-97.822},"postal":{}},"statusCode":"OK"}

Comment: How is the JSON relevant? You know how to decode JSON and how to access the keys within, that's apparent from the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
This seems that WWW::Curl::Easy require file handle.
Look at bold lines


 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use WWW::Curl::Easy;
 use Data::Dumper ;

 my $resp_body ="";

 my $curl=WWW::Curl::Easy->new;

 $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL,$url);

# Define file handle and send it to string 
 open (my $fh, ">", \$resp_body);

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$fh);

my $ret_code =$curl->perform;

if ($ret_code ==0){
 print "Response : $resp_body";
 }else{
 print "Error".$curl->errbuf ;
}
close($fh);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in the first example code block within the [WWW::Curl](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Curl#WWW::Curl::Easy) documentation. I've reproduced it here together with the code from the question.

```
my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL,$url);

# A filehandle, reference to a scalar or reference to a typeglob can be used here.
my $response_body;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response_body);

# Starts the actual request
my $retcode = $curl->perform;

my %hash = decode_json($response_body);
$country = $hash->{body}->{country};
```

You need to set a reference of some kind as the `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` option. We used a scalar reference, the variable `$response_body` will contain the response body after `$curl->perform` is done. You can then decode the JSON.

Comment: @KartikParihar that seems to be an internal URL. I cannot find a  DNS record for it. What do you have in `$response_body`? Is there anything in it at all?

Comment: $response_body is still empty. But when i run $curl->perform it print output to console as json string as attached above.

Comment: @Kartik Oh. That was not clear to me. You should edit your question and add that information. In that comment it was very hard to read. There are ways to capture STDOUT, but that is not really solving the problem but rather a workaround. Did you put the `\` in front of the variable for `WRITEDATA`?

Comment: JSON Output:     {"headers": {"ipAddress": ["192.2.2.2"], "type":["PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS"]},"body":{"cou‌​ntry":{"isoCode":"US","name":"United States","geoNameId":6252001},"continent":{"name":"North America","code":"NA","geoNameId":6255149},"city":{},"traits":{"ipAddress":"192.2‌​.2.2"},"location":{"latitude":37.751,"longitude":-97.822},"postal":{}},"statusCod‌​e":"OK"}

Comment: @simbabue-> No i haven't use ` in front of variable for WRITEDATA.

Comment: @kartik Oh. I bonked up the markup. Sorry about that. I meant a backslash ``\``.

Comment: Yes i used backslash.

Comment: Could you provide few workaround to capture STDOUT in variable.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling many times with this issue of WWW::Curl::Easy refusing to print to a variable, and constantly writing to STDOUT, I finally found the problem!

You want to get your WWW::Curl::Easy from **WWW-Curl-4.17** and **NOT from WWW::Curl::Easy found in WWW-Curl-3.02**.

So simply overwrite your previous WWW::Curl::Easy installation by the entire WWW-Curl 4.17 package:

http://search.cpan.org/~szbalint/WWW-Curl-4.17/lib/WWW/Curl.pm

Then it will obey to CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.
In fact, the other Curl does not even know CURLOPT_WRITEDATA as you will realize by adding **use strict**;